# Android studio 3.3 activity fragment + viewmodel template

Tags: android, android-studio

3.3 has dropped the activity fragment + ViewModel template.

I would like to stick with 3.3 for its new navigation editor. What steps do I need to take to replicate the dropped template?

Answer (score 2):

You can add activity by right click add activity and select activity+ViewsModal. Shown in screenshot[image: Add Activity + ViewModal Studio 3.3]

Comment: Thanks to both comments. In the 3.3 templates folder (per Darish) there is already a viewmodel template, which I imagine is what Vanshaj's method points to. Is there a way of changing settings so that template appears in the set up window when a new project is created?  (that is, where it used to appear under 3.2 - just seems it would save a little work - otherwise use Vanshaj's method). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

> What steps do I need to take to replicate the dropped template?

If you have the old `Android Studio 3.2` installed on your system, you can copy the template from the following location to new Android Studio

```
{ANDROID_STUDIO_LOCATION}\android\lib\templates\activities\ViewModelActivity
```